# Odd HTTP Status 404

Tags: tomcat

We have **Tomcat** with unexpanded application in it.

Inside war-file - we have some files... And some of them available via URL, but some - don't.

```
$ jar tf application-application/application-web-4.99.war | grep "01.png"
images/icons/01.png
```

It's OK and available via `http://someurl.com:8084/images/icons/01.png`

But second one:

```
$ jar tf application-application/application-web-4.99.war | grep UserGuide
userguide/UserGuide.pdf
images/UserGuide.pdf
```

Return HTTP Status 404 after `http://someurl.com:8084/images/UserGuide.pdf` or `http://oururl:8084/userguide/UserGuide.pdf`

Nothing in log-files, unfortunately.

Comment: How are you serving up the files?  

Is your app doing it?  Sometimes Spring or other frameworks will serve the files.  

The other option is to rely on Tomcat's default servlet.  If the app doesn't serve them and you haven't overridden the default servlet then it should serve up the files for you.

  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html

To troubleshoot, you might try temporarily enabling "listings".  That should let you see a directory listing for "images" and "userguide", which should let you know if the file is visible to Tomcat.

Comment: having a look on web.xml could be helpful if my memory of J2EE is correct